# Using iconv to convert mysqldump-ed databases

Tags: mysql, utf-8, iconv

Trying to quickly convert a latin1 mysql DB to utf8, I tried the following:

1. Dump the DB
2. run iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 on the resulting file
3. import into a fresh DB with UTF8 default encoding

This *mostly* works except... **some letters** get converted wrong (an example: uppercase accented 'U' becomes some garbled sequence starting with a question mark). Some conversion is taking place (od an a query result shows a two byte sequence where the latin1 byte was) and te latin1 version is alright. While I have so far been unsystematic in isolating the problem (late night; under deadline; etc.) the weirdness of the issue kills me: why would it fail on **some** letters and not all? Client connection? Column charset? Why I am not getting any diagnostics? I'm stymied.

Sure, I can work on isolating the issue and its details, but thought that maybe somebody ran into this already and can recognize it by this (admittedly rather poor) description.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

The data may have been **stored** as latin1 but it's possible that what ever client you used to dump the data has already exported it as UTF-8.

Open the dump file in a decent text editor (Notepad++, TextWrangler, Atom) and check which encoding allows all characters to be displayed properly.

Then when it comes to import the data back in, ensure your client is set to use UTF-8 on the **import**.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use iconv, it only muddies the works.

Assuming that a table is declared to be latin1 and correctly contains latin1 bytes, but you would like to change it to utf8, do this to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

It is also possible to do it with a dump and reload; it involves some changes to the arguments.  Sorry I don't have the details.

Comment: As I remember, changing the table charset does not convert whatever content is there.  Acording to some reading I did of late, doing what I want may be achieved by changing the **column**  character set - still haven't got aroun to try it, though.

Comment: You may have a point; you should test.  But note the word `CONVERT`, not `CHANGE`.